# Trying to redirect Chrome to new URL using Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am just starting out writing chrome extensions.
y first project: For certain sites, if you click on the extension, the extension will redirect Chrome to the current domainName/archive.

I am using `chrome.tabs.update();` to redirect.
If I try to redirect to a hard-coded URL such as`Yahoo.com`, it works correctly.

However, if I try to redirect so what I really want, such as `developer.google.com/archive` (which I know does not exist), the resulting URL Chrome tries to fetch is:

```
chrome-extension://injepfpghgbmjnecbgiokedggknlmige/developer.chrome.com/archive
```

**Chrome is prepending the extension's ID to the URL for some reason?**

In my background.js, I have the following:

```
 chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender) {
chrome.tabs.update( {url: request.redirect});
```

I got the code above from [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4859689/how-do-i-redirect-to-a-url-using-a-google-chrome-extension-content-script).

Someone else had the same issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10500787/chrome-tabs-url-redirecting) (but not answered)

The full options.js is:

```
function createButton () {
    chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
        var url = new URL(tab.url);
        var domain = url.hostname;
        archiveURL = domain + "/archive";

        let page = document.getElementById('buttonDiv');
        let button = document.createElement('button');

        button.addEventListener('click', function() {
            chrome.runtime.sendMessage({redirect: archiveURL}); // works if I send "Yahoo.com"
        });
        button.textContent = "> " + archiveURL; // So I know I am sending the right URL
        page.appendChild(button);

    })
}


createButton();
```

**SUMMARY:**
If I set:

```
 archiveURL = "http://sundxwn.tumblr.com/archive";
```

the system correctly goes to `http://sundxwn.tumblr.com/archive`.

**But...** if I set

```
archiveURL = domain + "/archive";
```

and confirm that the button text shows: `http://sundxwn.tumblr.com/archive`, 
Chrome tries to go to: `chrome-extension://injepfpghgbmjnecbgiokedggknlmige/sundxwn.tumblr.com/archive`

Any help would be truly appreciated.

Comment: Should be `var domain = url.origin;`

Comment: WOW.   THANK YOU !!!! Can you please explain?   url.hostname seemed to give the right answer when I put it as text in the button... what is the difference?  Hard to find this online...

Answer (score 0):

`url.hostname` is just that, the hostname. For the original URL `https://example.com/some/path`, it would be `example.com`.

Then, your constructed URL is `example.com/archive`. It does not start with a protocol (e.g. `http://`) or a slash, so it's interpreted as a *relative* URL to the current page's URL.

And you are calling this from some extension page, e.g. `page.html` or the auto-generated background page. Its URL is, for example:

`chrome-extension://injepfpghgbmjnecbgiokedggknlmige/page.html`

So, to construct an absolute URL from a relative URL, Chrome chops that path off at the last slash and adds your relative part.

You *need* to specify the protocol so that Chrome understands it's a URL that has nothing to do with the current document. And `url.origin` does that, it would be `https://example.com`, which then is properly interpreted.